# Visual Studio: Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path

Tags: sqlite, dll, visual-studio-2017

I am suddenly receiving a strange build error on my UWP (Xamarin Forms) project which uses Akavache SQLite:

```
Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2.dll'. Source files: 
C:\Users\User\.nuget\packages\SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite3\1.1.8\lib\uap10.0\SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2.dll
C:\Users\User\.nuget\packages\SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green\1.1.2\lib\uap10.0\SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2.dll
```

I don't really know what I did to trigger this; the only thing I know I changed between the time it did not work and the time it did is to associate the project with a store app package...

The UWP project is referencing two other projects, the head xamarin forms project, and a separate core library with other shared mobile components. both have reference to and use the Akavache library, and I do see that dll referenced in all three of the projects.

I tried changing the Copy Local to False for this batteries_v2.dll but that didn't fix it. I also tried cleaning the project and also manually deleting my bin/obj folders but that also didn't help...

what the heck did I do?

Comment: it appears adding the nuget package: SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green fixed the issue; apparently there was already a reference (somehow??) to 1.1.2 as shown above, adding the latest via nuget updated it to 1.1.8 and the project builds. not sure what happened so I am annoyed, but glad it's fixed

Comment: Were you ever able to find the reference?  I'm running into this exact same problem, and installed SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green, but the problem continues.  I can't seem to find the source of the problem...

Comment: also getting this same problem

Comment: I honestly don't remember how I fixed this sorry. I think I ended up removing all the references and the vs extension for sqlite and adding them from nuget manually. but it's been so long I really can't say for sure. if I come across this issue again I'll certainly post my fix, sorry!